# Format array elements from one form to another -JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings that are actually dates in the form of `201001 ,201002.` I would like to convert those array items to something like **2010 January, 2010 February.** Is there any way to do this.

```
var Array = ["201005", "201006", "201007", "201008", "201009", "201010", "201011", "201012", "201101", "201102", "201103", "201104", "201106", "201107", "201108", "201109", "201110", "201111", "201112", "201201", "201202", "201203", "201204", "201205", "201206", "201207", "201208", "201209", "201210", "201211", "201212", "201301", "201302", "201303", "201304", "201305", "201306", "201307"];
```

**I'm looking for an array like :**

```
var expected = ["2010 january", "2010 February" etc]
```

Comment: Quick answer is "Yes, there is a way to do it." If you're asking how, then you will have to show us some code and be specific about what you're stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
const monthMap = {
  "01": "January",
  "02": "February",
  "03": "March",
  "04": "April",
  "05": "May",
  "06": "June",
  "07": "July",
  "08": "August",
  "09": "September",
  "10": "October",
  "11": "November",
  "12": "December"
};

xAxisArray = xAxisArray.map(axis => {
  const year = axis.substring(0, 4);
  const month = axis.substring(4, 6);

  return `${year} ${monthMap[month]}`;
});
```

Or you could use [moment](https://momentjs.com/), but that might be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can try my code

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];

  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return year + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex];
}


var result = xAxisArray.map(item => {
  var strDate = item.slice(0, 4) + '-' + item.slice(4, 6) + '-01'

  return formatDate(new Date(strDate))
})
console.log(result)
```

This is a demo: https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/xxKgKYp

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
var xAxisArray = ["201005", "201006", "201007", "201008", "201009", "201010", "201011", "201012", "201101", "201102", "201103", "201104", "201106", "201107", "201108", "201109", "201110", "201111", "201112", "201201", "201202", "201203", "201204", "201205", "201206", "201207", "201208", "201209", "201210", "201211", "201212", "201301", "201302", "201303", "201304", "201305", "201306", "201307"];

//Array to link month number to name
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

//Result array
var formattedArray = [];

//Loop through the old array and push the formatted date to the new array
xAxisArray.forEach(function(element) {
  var formatted = element.substr(0,4) + '-' + element.substr(4); //Add the dash between year and month
  var date = new Date(formatted); //Create date object
  var year = date.getFullYear(); //Get the year
  var month = date.getMonth(); //Get the month

  formattedArray.push(year + ' ' + monthNames[month]);
});

console.log(formattedArray);
```

First, create a date from the string. Then convert that date to the desired format and last add the new formatted string to a new array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the full name of the month, and not just the first three letter, you need to have them somewhere, for example:

```
const MONTHS = [
  "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
```

Then you can simply have:

```
const format = (value) => {
  // assuming the format is 4 digits followed by 2 digits
  const [, year, month] = value.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})/);
  return `${year} ${MONTHS[month - 1]}`
}
```

Then you can map your array such as:

```
const expected = xAxisArray.map(format);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can get your answer by following approach .

```
xAxisArray.forEach(function(value , index){
    var last2 = value.slice(-2);
    const date = new Date(value.slice(4), last2);  // 2009-11-10
    const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
    xAxisArray[index] = value.substring(0,4) +" "+ month;
});
```

Your problem will get solve .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `moment` library for this:

```
const result = xAxisArray.map(item => {
  const year = item.substring(0,4)
  const month = item.substring(4,2)
  return moment(`01/${month}/${year}`).format('YYYY MMMM')
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

By using moment.js libary you can convert , use below expression convert it

moment("your value").format("YYYY MMM");

ex:moment(201005).format("YYYY MMM");